# How to write `jmp $+1` with GAS syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86

In NASM syntax, we can write `jmp $+1`, my question is how to write `jmp $+1` using GAS syntax ?

Comment: Have you tried `jmp .+1`?

Comment: Note that you're asking how to write a jump to the 2nd byte of the jmp instruction.  i.e. to use the first byte of the displacement as the start of a new instruction.  That's not the same thing as encoding a jump with `rel8 = +1` to skip over the next byte after the instruction.